# Problems altering font icon set in Fontlab

Tags: fonts, icon

I found a nice social icon set as font: http://www.tajfa.com/projects/rondo/

What I now want is to **remove the circular borders** around them, but when I open them with **Fontlab Studio 5** I only see a blank set. Is there a way to remove it or do you know of alternative sets?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you want to do, preferably in what software? Do you want to edit the characters and re-save the font as, say, *.otf; or do you just want to create icons (vector / raster) based upon this font? The latter is really easy and is good enough for most applications of social icons.

Comment: @Bakabaka I want to remove circles around the logos, then use it in my web projects, I tryed to do it with Fontlab, but icons gone, I think Fontlab changed the order of charset, or something like that

Comment: Can't you simply type out the characters you need in Photoshop, rasterise the text and remove/mask the circle manually? I don't see the need to edit the font file.

Comment: @Bakabaka I want to use it as font, because color, background color, and size of icons will be dynamic, Static sprites are useless for this condition.

Comment: What steps are you taking to remove the circles? I don't seem to be experiencing the same issue: http://i.imgur.com/QTjWdJ9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font has a Creative Commons license, so you are authorized to modify it. I don't know why you are having this problem, but if you can't find a solution you can always check one of the other icon sets that work with font-face and don't require you to change the shapes:

- [Modern Pictograms](http://thedesignoffice.org/project/modern-pictograms)
- [A Free Icon Web Font](http://www.heydonworks.com/article/a-free-icon-web-font)
- [Iconic Icon Set](http://somerandomdude.com/work/iconic/)

And [some more here](http://speckyboy.com/2012/02/13/20-fontface-icon-sets/)

Comment: Finally I got an answer, thank you! http://fontfabric.com/social-media-icons-pack/ looks pretty good, and suit to my project. I dont know why I couldnt alter Rondo properly, although I used Fontlab for many fonts. Thank you again.